# UIPopover dismiss behavior different between iOS SDK 5.0 and SDK 5.1

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uipopovercontroller, popover, dismiss

## DESCRIPTION OF THE INTERFACE

In the detail view of a split view, a programmatically drawn button calls (when clicked) a popover showing a text linked to the button's title.

Here is an abstract of the IBAction method :

```
DefinitionsPopoverViewController *defPVC = [[DefinitionsPopoverViewController alloc] init];
defPVC.delegate = self;
defPVC.definition = aDefinition;

UIPopoverController *defPC = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:defPVC];
defPC.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(480.0, popoverHeight);
[defPC presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame
    inView:self
    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
    animated:YES];
defPC.delegate = self;
self.definitionPopover = defPC;
```

### Content of the popover

The UIPopover contains a VC with a UIWebView.

## BEHAVIOR

In iOS 5.0 SDK, the behavior is normal : the popover appears then is dismissed when I touch outisde the popover area.

In iOS 5.1 SDK, the popover appears normally. Once visible, links in the UIWebView are operating normally. But every touch outside the popover does not dismiss the popover. Application seems frozen. No warning and no bug in XCode 4.2/4.3.

For the moment, I decided to keep my app developped under SDK 5.0 waiting for a solution to this issue.

Comment: I am experiencing this as well.